# Are Remote observers and observables possible in Spring-Flux reactor streams?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm currently reviewing as much information as I can about functional reactive programming.

I'm trying to design a service which is event driven and uses the reactive stream as the center piece.

I'm failing to see a remote subscriber? Do all observers and observables need to be local to the machine? Or can I create micro services and allow external or remote services subscribe to the stream?

I am assuming this is possible, but the implementation is not native.

The idea am I researching is for an Observer to subscribe to the emitted events from a remote Observable. (Micro Services)

Comment: Reactor is indeed fully local. To work with microservices you need to look at something like [Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html). Although, using JSON for inter-service communication is generally a Bad Idea TM.